# Sqlite3 with Flask used in different ways?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm now working with CRUD project with Flask and SQLite3. Here is my code

```
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('SELECT name, lastname FROM customer')
    x = [dict(name=row[0], lastname=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('hello.html', customer=x)
```

I'm very new programming and very new to database too. I have read the Flask documentation, this one: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlite3/ and find it so confuse. what is the benefit of following the step provide in flask doc? what are the concept behind it? I really lost of what they are doing. Can I still do it in my way like the code above? or should I change my self to use the flask doc style? I'm now doing a basic CRUD app for restaurant inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is create a database on the application context, and that's why you use flask.g, and then close it when it's not needed anymore (i.e. when the request is closed).

That and your code are mostly the same, however flask doc's one will just "work" better since you won't have to manually close the connection every request and it will open only if necessary.

Comment: If I use this set of code:

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = connect_to_database()
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

I don't have to write this g.db = connect_db() and this g.db.close() in my def hello(): right? I only write cur = get_db().cursor() so it will be less work for me? because those are included?

Comment: What do you mean database on the application context? do you mean it is for testing purpose? If I make the real app will this code suit with my project?

Comment: It means that the database is not stored in the request but for all the application. As for the first question, yes.